# Is it possible to see how much `Exceptions` my app threw?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I got some (old, old) console-apps which work on big databases and process some data.
While processing the data, exceptions are thrown and caught. Unfortunately this is intended in some cases, if a record is invalid.

I would like to measure if the count of exceptions is in a acceptable range.

#### Example

Processing 100.000 records, 20 `Exceptions` caught => Normal run.

Processing 100.000 records, 10.000`Exceptions` caught => That's a problem.

#### Example-Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomething();

    int x = HowMuchErrorsDidICatch(); // This is where 

    Console.WriteLine("This run catched {0} Exception.", x);
}

// Some work to do..
static void DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            // .. Processing some Data
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorCount++;
            // Handling the Exception
        }
    }
}

#region What i'm searching for
// I hope to get those number from .Net
static int errorCount = 0;
private static int HowMuchErrorsDidICatch()
{
    return errorCount;
}
#endregion
```

Because of the amount of existing code it's not an option to modify every catch-block.

Does anybody know a way to get the catch-count from .Net?

Comment: Try hooking onto `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` and see if that helps you out. You won't be able to detect whether it will be handled or not though, only that it was thrown. Additionally, and this should be obvious, this piece of code needs to be foolproof, if the code that is called when an exception occurs start throwing exceptions, well, you can probably imagine what happens.

Comment: I wish i had a flamethrower to use when I see coding practices like those. @LasseVågsætherKarlsen nice answer ;-)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Thank you, that's what i'm searching for. I'm currently trying to reduce the exception-spamming but bcause of the bunch of code i got no feeling where to start :D

Comment: Exceptions are usually last resort in terms of error handling, if you expect invalid data you ideally shouldn't be using exceptions for this, instead create a filter/validator that checks the data according to all the rules before attempting to do something that requires the data to be valid. ie. if you validate that the data is good before calling `SaveToDatabase`, and you want `SaveToDatabase` to do a last check *it* should throw an exception, but the validator should be more along "yes/no" or "here are all the problems with the data, no problems = ok".

Comment: Totaly correct. The crazy thing is, that there are validators which check the data and generate invalid-record-lists, but unfortunately in some places exceptions are used for this. I want to introduce this counter to remove those step by step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> Occurs when an exception is thrown in managed code, before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain.

Here's sample code for your scenario:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) => errorCount++;
```

**Note**: Do **not** get creative with code in this event handler. It **must never** throw an exception that you don't handle. If exceptions bubble out of this event handler the event will be called recursively. As such I would leave the code as shown above, do not try to log the exceptions or whatnot in this event handler.

Additionally, I believe the event handler may be called from multiple threads, so the code really need to be foolproof. In the above scenario you may end up loosing count of a few exceptions if you have a lot of exceptions on many threads, in that case you might want to rewrite the code to:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) => Interlocked.Increment(ref errorCount);
```

However, this is probably only needed if you need the *exact* number of exceptions. If you just want to get a hint of the amount, stay with `++`.

Comment: Concise and elegant! Love it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) framework, for instance, [PostSharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling)

For each of the method where exception may occur, add below attributes:

```
[PrintException] //Add this
public void DoSomething(string someArg)
{
    //whatever actions
}
```

In order to customize the exception handling logic, you need to derive the PrintException from OnExceptionAspect:

```
[PSerializable]
public class PrintExceptionAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.Message); // This is whatever you want to handle the exception
    }
}
```

This way, you do not need to make intrusive modifications, but weave your code with AOP attributes.